# What distance (comoving, proper, light travel time distance) does the cosmic distance ladder actually give us?

Tags: cosmology, distance

In most material I can find on the cosmic distance ladder for a lay-level reader like myself, it never seems to explicitly say what distance its talking about.

There is the proper distance when the light was emitted, and the comoving distance, where the light source is now.

The light we are receiving however has traveled a different distance, the light travel time distance, which is less than the comoving distance and greater than the proper distance at emission time.

What does the distance ladder actually measure? How could it be less than or greater than the distance light actually traveled?

Comment: The distance to the CMB is usually given as a time estimate between emission and  absorption (13+ billion years) and cosmological distances are best expressed as redshift since these are actually measurable phenomena. There is really no useful "physical distance" to objects that are not in causal contact with us any longer. All we are seeing of them are afterimages of their past state. Just my two cents as an experimentalist. A theorist will probably tell you about all the distance numbers we can calculate for far away objects... but they are just numbers without much physical meaning.

Comment: The first couple of rungs on the ladder are clearly local.